# Always enable 'use strict'; by default?

Tags: javascript, browserify

I use [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) to break my app into modules.
I wonder if I can somehow enable `'use strict';` so that it was applied to all the code I write in for the project?

Or may be it's possible to configure node to always use strict mode locally for some folders/files, or the whole project?

Comment: Begin every js file with 'use strict'? Many IDEs and editors have the "template setting" where a snippet of text (mostly copyright) is inserted at every new file matching a certain type.

Comment: IIRC if 'use strict'; is the first line of the global context, it applies globally.  Note that this may not be desirable.

Comment: @Paul: Yes, that would appear to be the goal.

Comment: I would recommend to use babel in addition to browserify. Babel will handle this for you.

https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-strict-mode/

Answer (score 0):

There is a great browserify transform for that: [strictify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/strictify). It inserts a `'use strict'` in the closure of your modules.

Just update your package.json with the following:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "strictify": "^0.2.0"
},
"browserify": {
  "transform": [
    "strictify"
  ]
}
```